# The database does not collect the content other than English [Charset/Unicode set to UTF-8]

Tags: html, unicode, character-encoding

I have moved my server from dreamhost to Godaddy recently

When I was with Dreamhost it was no problem when my visitors submitting a form in my website using other language than English.

For example they use Thai language when they submit the form I receive it with no problem.

but what happen now when they submit any form I will receive a text like `??????????` so I though it might be just the setting on the php.ini file if that was set correctly and I see it was using UTF-8

```
; PHP's built-in default is text/html
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

and

```
exif.encode_unicode = "UTF-8"
exif.decode_unicode_motorola = "UCS-2BE"
exif.decode_unicode_intel = "UCS-2LE"
;exif.encode_jis = 
exif.decode_jis_motorola = JIS
exif.decode_jis_intel = JIS
```

but I can't figure out why this is happen while all was set correctly

and each of my html/php header file I have included

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Any suggestion what I missed?

---

To put some more information that

If I use the FTP client such as Filezilla there will be another problem that when I edit the file .php or .html the content in the file if it has any other language than English it will go all like question mark `???????` but if I edit it from the web like Net2ftp then it has no problem on that

Comment: Exif? Does this question have to do with picture metadata?

Comment: well the two of the quote I included above is from the php.ini file

Comment: Sorry you had to move to GoDaddy...

Comment: @Kyle you mean I have to ask Godaddy? or you mean too bad that I moved to Godaddy? LOL

Comment: @Kyle I don't know if they would even answer my question about this matter :/ they always wanted me to find out my own :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with PHP + MySQL, MySQL refused to properly store UTF8 strings. The solution was to tell MySQL each time after connection, to use UTF8. I believe the SQL command to do so was `SET CHARACTER SET UTF8`, or `SET NAMES UTF8` but I'm not sure, it was a long ago.

Edit: Found some old PHP code of mine, I hope it is helpful:

```
function sql_connect(){

global $host,$user,$pass,$dbname,$conn;

//  connect to mysql
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

//  if cannot connect, exit
if(!$conn){
    die('Cannot connect to MySQL server: '.mysql_errno().' - '.mysql_error());
};

//  if cannot set to utf8, exit
if(!mysql_query('set names utf8;',$conn)){
    mysql_close($conn);
    die('Cannot set to UTF8: '.mysql_errno().' - '.mysql_error());
};

//  if cannot select database, exit
if(!mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn)){
    mysql_close($conn);
    die('Cannot select database: '.mysql_errno().' - '.mysql_error());
};

};


function sql_to_html($x){
return(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($x),ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8"));
};
```

Comment: Thanks but is there any more information where can I look to about the command to set the character?

Comment: and also how can I use the command while the submission is in the Wordpress and another is my own .php file

Comment: I guess MySQL documentation has some information about character sets. The set names command goes right after you have connected to the server/database, it is a simple SQL query.

Comment: the above codes needs to be place in where? sorry I'm kinda new on mysql stuff

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to set PHP's internal encoding to UTF8 using [iconv_set_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php). Your php.ini preferences only affect the HTTP headers that are sent with your document! Finally, make sure you pass the encoding to mangling functions like `htmlentities`.